# Fragmentation Tab open By Default 3rd tab

Tags: android

I have Create Fragment Tab where 6 Tab are available when we call this tab then it open by default first tab but we want to implement when we call this page then its by default open 3rd tab how bto resolve it please suggest.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        tabHost = FindViewById<TabHost>(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
        tabHost.Setup();

        viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
        tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, tabHost, viewPager);

        tabsAdapter.AddTab(tabHost.NewTabSpec("Sale").SetIndicator("Sale"), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(retailerStockSaleList.PageFragment)), null);
        tabsAdapter.AddTab(tabHost.NewTabSpec("L Y S M Sale").SetIndicator("L Y S M Sale"), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(retailerStockSale1List.PageFragment)), null);
        tabsAdapter.AddTab(tabHost.NewTabSpec("L M Sale").SetIndicator("L M Sale"), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(retailerStockSaleLMList.PageFragment)), null);
        tabsAdapter.AddTab(tabHost.NewTabSpec("Stock").SetIndicator("Stock"), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(retailerPhysicalStockList.PageFragment)), null);
        tabsAdapter.AddTab(tabHost.NewTabSpec("Order List").SetIndicator("Order List"), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(retailerOrderList.PageFragment)), null);
        tabsAdapter.AddTab(tabHost.NewTabSpec("Retailer Details").SetIndicator("Retailer Details"), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(retailerDetail.PageFragment)), null);

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            tabHost.SetCurrentTabByTag(bundle.GetString("tab"));
        }
    }


    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.PutString("tab", tabHost.CurrentTabTag);

    }

    protected class TabsAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter, TabHost.IOnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
    {
        private Context _context;
        private TabHost _tabHost;
        private ViewPager _viewPager;
        private List<TabInfo> _tabs = new List<TabInfo>();

        public class TabInfo
        {

            public string tag;
            public Class clss;
            public Bundle args;
            public Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment { get; set; }

            public TabInfo(string _tag, Class _class, Bundle _args)
            {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public class DummyTabFactory : Java.Lang.Object, TabHost.ITabContentFactory
        {
            private Context _context;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }

            public View CreateTabContent(string tag)
            {
                var v = new View(_context);
                v.SetMinimumHeight(0);
                v.SetMinimumWidth(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager)
            : base(activity.SupportFragmentManager)
        {
            _context = activity;
            _tabHost = tabHost;
            _viewPager = pager;
            _tabHost.SetOnTabChangedListener(this);
            _viewPager.Adapter = this;
            _viewPager.SetOnPageChangeListener(this);

        }


        public void AddTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class clss, Bundle args)
        {
            tabSpec.SetContent(new DummyTabFactory(_context));
            var tag = tabSpec.Tag;

            var info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

            _tabs.Add(info);
            _tabHost.AddTab(tabSpec);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
               return _tabs.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            var info = _tabs[position];
            return Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.Instantiate(_context, info.clss.Name, info.args);
        }

        public void OnTabChanged(string tabId)
        {
            int position ;
            position = _tabHost.CurrentTab;    
            _viewPager.CurrentItem = position;
        }

        public void OnPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {

        }

        public void OnPageSelected(int position)
        {
            var widget = _tabHost.TabWidget;
            var oldFocusability = widget.DescendantFocusability;
            widget.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
            _tabHost.CurrentTab = position;
            widget.DescendantFocusability = oldFocusability;
        }



    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried setcurrentTab method of tabhost check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29

Comment: What about using: "*tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabIndex);*" ?